# How I access ClientCredentials from with a custom IChannel or IChannelFactory?

Tags: c#, wcf, credentials

I'm creating a custom channel in WCF in order to implement a custom security protocol. No, don't run away! It's not that scary!

Verifying the protocol on the service is relatively simple. The hard part is adding the security information to the request based on the client credentials.

What I want to do is access the `ClientCredentials` object (the one attached to the `ClientProxy` in use) from within my channel implementation. Normally, I'd get access to this through the [`Behaviors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.serviceendpoint.behaviors.aspx) property on the `ServiceEndpoint` instance for the endpoint I'm trying to reach:

```
var credentials = channel.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to access the service endpoint the channel is associated with from within the channel itself - almost zero metadata is available from the `ChannelBase` class.

Is there a way to get the endpoint my channel is associated with? Is there any alternative way to access the client credentials on the client-side?

Comment: Hi tragedian... I am trying to do the same thing...but i am not able to do it....was you able to achieve the same thing. if yes then can you give me some guidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard security channels don't use `ClientCredentials` internally. They instead talk with `SecurityTokenManager` which is constructed from `ClientCredentials`. I recommend using some disassembler to browse whole implementation.

Generally your `BindingElement` should build both `ChannelLister` and `ChannelFactory` and pass them all information they need.

Comment: How interesting... `SecurityTokenManager` is the base class for client and server token credential managers. I will reflect on how they are used in the WCF pipeline for more answers.

Comment: It took a lot of going-around, but eventually I added the `BindingContext` to my listener and factory constructors, which gave access to the behaviours and exposed credentials I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Implement you own client service.

For example;

```
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Channels;


public class UserClient : ClientBase<IAsyncESPUserService> , IESPUserService
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor - No Parameters, this will use a default target endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        public UserClient() : base() { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor - Binding and Address Parameters
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="binding">How we are communicating.</param>
        /// <param name="address">The address we are communicating to.</param>
        public UserClient(Binding binding, EndpointAddress address) : base(binding, address) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor - Configuration Name Parameter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="endpointConfigurationName">The name of the configuration in ServiceReferences.ClientConfig. </param>
        public UserClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : base(endpointConfigurationName) { }

           //Implement your async service calls here       
}
```

Now call it...

```
//Create using the default endpoint
UserClient client = new UserClient();


//Set user name and password with call
System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials loginCredentials = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials();
loginCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
loginCredentials.UserName.Password = "test";

//Attach Credentials, Can't do this in config file
var defaultCredentials = client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials>();
client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(defaultCredentials);
client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(loginCredentials);

//Now make a call to a service method...
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't make the information available to the inner channels at all.